# Hostings que utilizam JSP

Tags: java, jsp, cpanel

Tenho um *web hosting linux* que coloco todos os meus sistemas em PHP, sendo que agora preciso trabalhar com a extensão (*.JSP) e tenho algumas duvidas

- Que tipo de host utilizo para rodar JSP?
- O CPanel roda JSP automaticamente?
- O que preciso fazer para funcionar JSP e PHP no mesmo servidor?

Comment: Sua pergunta poderá ser fechada por não cumprir os termos do site (baseada em opiniões). Mas recomendo a integrator.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi direito a sua pergunta, e vou tentar dar uma resposta objetiva, neutra e não baseada em opiniões. Mas confesso que essa não é uma das melhores respostas que poderiam ser dadas.

> Que tipo de host utilizo para rodar JSP?

Você pode usar Tomcat, JBoss, Glassfish, ou qualquer outro container para Servlets e JSP.

> O CPanel roda JSP automaticamente?

Acho que sim. Talvez você possa ver mais aqui: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/cpanel-tomcat-jsp-and-servlets-guide.282922/ - Não vou detalhar isso mais profundamente, pois não possuo conhecimento para tal.

> O que preciso fazer para funcionar JSP e PHP no mesmo servidor?

Apenas botar os dois para rodar no mesmo servidor. Entretanto, eles deverão estar em portas TCP diferentes. Uma forma simples de fazer isso seria rodar o PHP na porta 80 e o seu servidor Servlets/JSP em uma porta 8080, por exemplo.

Caso você precise de tudo na porta 80, você pode:

- Utilizar *server side includes*, o que permite você até mesmo misturar o conteúdo gerado pelo JSP e pelo PHP em uma mesma página, embora isso não seja uma tarefa simples.
- Colocar algum serviço de proxy (ex: Apache) no seu servidor na porta 80 e utilizá-lo para redirecionar as requisições para o PHP ou para o JSP de acordo com algum critério. O JSP estaria rodando em uma porta diferente da 80. O PHP poderia estar rodando dentro do Apache mesmo (ou não).